# EF Code First Query and assign without savechanges

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

```
new ProductReadModel
{
    Nr = (nr++).ToString(),
    Abbreviation = "Ewb",
    Name = "Some product",
    BodyMaterial = context.BodyMaterialReadModels.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Abbreviation == "EDTA")
}
```

During database initialization I try to fill my tables with the EF code first seeder. In one of my seeders I add all the bodymaterials. In this one I try to relate these bodymaterials to products. When I debug I see my bodymaterial collections counts 14 items. However after going through this code the BodyMaterial property is `null`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing database query against empty database. Try this instead:

```
BodyMaterial = context.BodyMaterialReadModels.Local.FirstOrDefault(...);
```

or use your `BodyMaterialCollection` directly. The set exposed on the context is entry point to the database not to your not persisted entities (except `Local` property).

Comment: Great that did the trick. Somehow the intellisense isn't showing me this property but it compiles and works.